# Why is my SQL Insert Duplicating

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So I've got an AJAX call on a client-side page that is reaching the server and executing. However, for every submit I'm getting 2 insert statements. I can't figure out for the life of me where this second insert is coming from. Maybe a new set of eyes could shed some light on it.

Form (in .blade.php):

```
{!! Form::open(array('action'=>'PhishingController@createNewProject')) !!}
{!! Form::label('projectNameText','Project Name: ') !!}
{!! Form::text('projectNameText',null,array('name'=>'projectNameText')) !!}
{!! Form::label('projectAssigneeText','Project Assignee') !!}
{!! Form::text('projectAssigneeText',null,array('name'=>'projectAssigneeText')) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Submit',array('id'=>'submitButton')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

PHP Controller:

```
$projectName = $request->input('projectNameText');
$projectAssignee = $request->input('projectAssigneeText');
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$db = $this->openDatabaseDefault();
$sql = "INSERT INTO database.table(PRJ_ProjectId,PRJ_ProjectName,PRJ_ProjectAssignee,PRJ_ProjectStart,
            PRJ_ProjectLastActive,PRJ_ProjectStatus,PRJ_ProjectTotalUsers,PRJ_EmailViews,PRJ_WebsiteViews,
            PRJ_ProjectTotalReports) VALUES (null,'$projectName','$projectAssignee','$date','$date','Inactive',0,0,0,0);";
if(!$projects = $db->query($sql)) {
        echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing technical difficulties.";
        echo "Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: \n";
        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
        echo "Errno: " . $db->errno . "\n";
        echo "Error: " . $db->error . "\n";
        exit;
}
$db->close();
return redirect()->to('http://localhost:8888/generateEmails');
```

AJAX:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
        console.log("clicked");
        var projectName = $('#projectNameText').val();
        var projectAssignee = $('#projectAssigneeText').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            //url: "http://localhost:8888/projects/create",
            data: {projectNameText: projectName, projectAssigneeText: projectAssignee}
        })
    });
});
```

Anything is appreciated at this point.

Comment: In the js console how many clicked message do you see per click? 1 or 2?

Comment: Only one clicked comes through. At one point I had even put an Else statement on the controller to see if the If Statement was double executing. It only echo'd out once.

Comment: you call `return redirect()->to('http://localhost:8888/generateEmails');` in ajax related php file? to me that part seems weird

Comment: The goal of the redirect is once the insert has happened I send it to another page. The idea behind this process is that a user is creating a "Project" that sends out emails. They can select a project or create a new one when they are forming a new job. When they opt to create a new one, they get redirected to this forum. After they create the new project, I'm just sending them back to their previous page to continue working on the new job. Localhost is just because it's in development. It would be a fully qualified domain once put live.

Comment: do you understand meaning of ajax? usually when you call ajax, you should expect some simple response, but in your case I guess your ajax call get back full html page? what do you do with that page?

Comment: Yes. I'm asynchronously sending data elsewhere. In this case, I'm sending text pulled from two text fields in a forum to a server to be inserted into my database. Then I'm redirecting them back to the project they were originally working on. The AJAX call itself is more a less a fire and forget. Once it's sent to the server, the server will send a response back to say received but I could care less about that. All that matters to me is the insert and then sending the user back to the job they were working on.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I am afraid You do not understand ajax concept. you should at least catch if your ajax call was succeed or not http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp and then do your redirection on frontend (js) side but not on php side.

Comment: While that does answer a design flaw, that doesn't answer my question of why am I getting duplicate inserts. I'll work on modifying my code to work to basic conceptual standards while the question get's answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex for the conceptual ajax change. Turns out the PHP redirect was causing my method to fire again before it redirected. Don't know why, but by pushing the redirect into a AJAX success function it fixed my duplicate inserts.

Revised AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: {projectNameText: projectName, projectAssigneeText: projectAssignee},
    success: function() {
        window.location.replace("http://localhost:8888/generateEmails");
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {
        alert('Unable to create new project.');
        console.log("xhr: " + xhr);
        console.log('status: ' + status);
        console.log('error: ' + error);
    }
});
```